# Can I express named Python string arguments more succintly?

Tags: python, string

I know of two ways to include named arguments in a string:

```
name = "Mary"
pet = "lamb"

# option 1
message = "%(name)s had a little %(pet)s" % {"name": name, "pet": pet}
print(message)

# option 2
message = "{name} had a little {pet}"
message.format(name = name, pet = pet)
print(message)
# I'm not actually sure if `name = name` works, usually these are different
```

I don't think either of these is very readable. Is there any way to reduce the number of times I repeat variable names here?

It is important that the string arguments are named (not empty) so that:

- they can be repeated in the string: `%(name)s %(name)s quite contrary how does your %(pet)s grow?`
- they are visible when translating strings: `%(name)s alikuwa kidogo %(pet)s`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With an object:**

```
person.name = 'foo'
person.age = 12
```

You can do:

```
print '{name} is {age} old'.format(**person.__dict__)
```

**With a dictionary:**

```
a = {'name': 'foo', age: 12}
print '{name} is {age} old'.format(**a)
```

**With a list/tuple/set/namedtuple:**

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = (1,2,3)
c = set([1,2,3,1])

from collections import namedtuple
Foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'x y z')
foo = Foo(1,2,3)
print '{} {} {}'.format(*foo)


print '{} {} {}'.format(*a)
print '{} {} {}'.format(*b)
print '{} {} {}'.format(*c)
print '{} {} {}'.format(*foo)
```

However, the `namedtuple` is more than a tuple, it is also an object, so you can also do this:

```
print '{x} {z} {y}'.format(**foo._asdict())
```

The list could be longer, I'll stop here, but now you get an idea...

Answer (score 2):

You can just have empty `{}` brackets in the format string. And by the way in the second one, you need to set the call to format equal to a variable as it doesn't work in-place:

```
message = '{} had a little {}'.format(name, pet)  # < v2.7 needs numbers in brackets.
```

Comment: Additionally, if there are a lot of arguments to ```format()```, one can simply use ```str.format(*list_of_args_in_order)```

Comment: This does require 2.7 or newer, otherwise you need to number them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, I've put a little comment in. Though OP appears to be using Python 3.

Comment: updated explaining that I'm looking for named arguments specifically - but good to know! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary reduces the number of times you need to reference the argument names...

```
# stand-in for actual calculations
madlib = {}
madlib["name"] = "Mary"
madlib["pet"] = "lamb"

# this is the simplified bit
message = "%(name)s had a little %(pet)s" % madlib
print(message)
```

(Only remaining question, then, is if using a dictionary for storage is un-Pythonic.)

Comment: This is a quite long-winded, I wouldn't call it pythonic.

Comment: Do not answer your own questions!

Comment: @Apero hi, there is nothing wrong with answering your own question (although I admit speaking in the first person was not appropriate and I have fixed it)

Comment: @AlexThornton clarified that the first bit isn't intended to be - my concern is if "storing" things in a dictionary is a no-no

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I'm lazy I use `locals()` for this purpose:

```
>>> name = "Mary"
>>> pet = "lamb"
>>> "{name}, {name}, quite contrary, how does your {pet} grow?".format(**locals())
'Mary, Mary, quite contrary, how does your lamb grow?'
```

This doesn't require construction of a special object, but that could just as easily be viewed as a weakness, not a strength.

Answer (score 0):

you are not forced to use variable names inside the bracket , you can use empty `{}` :

```
>>> "{} had a little {}".format(name,pet)
'Mary had a little lamb'
```

also you can use `string.Template`:

```
>>> import string
>>> new_style = string.Template('$i had a little $j')
>>> print new_style.substitute(i='Mary',j='lamb')
Mary had a little lamb
>>> print new_style.substitute({'i':'Mary','j':'lamb'}) # use dictionary
Mary had a little lamb
```